# Complexity of T(n)=16T(n/4)-2n^2

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, recurrence

I'm having difficulties solving this recurrence relation: T(n)=16T(n/4)-2n^2. From my understanding I can't use the master theorem because f(n) is only allowed to be positive. Because of that I tried using the recurrence method:

```
T(n) = 16T(n/4)-2n^2
T(n) = 16(16T(n/16)-2(n/4)^2)-2n^2
T(n) = 16(16(16T(n/64)-2(n/16)^2)-2(n/4)^2)-2n^2
```

So this brings me to:

```
T(n) = 16^i * T(n/4^i) - (i*2*n^2)

T(n) terminates when n/4^i=1 so i = log4(n)
```

When I insert this into the equation I get:

```
T(n) = 16^log4(n) - (2*n^2*log4(n))
```

So would this bring me to a complexity of

```
T(n) = θ(n^2*log4(n)) ?
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Plug your result in the recurrence and check.

Comment: And what's your question about this? How is this related to programming?

Comment: Yes, the computational complexity of T(n) is (n^2)log(n). you can also use Akra-Bazzi theorem for the proof.

Comment: - (i*2*n^2) is wrong. Expand the recurrence one more time to get an idea.